# How to serialize array of object as JSON dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to serialize an array of objects as JSON dictionary.

Array item like this:

```cs
class Entry {
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;}
}
```

So array like

```
var arr = new[]
    {
        new Entry{Id = "one", Value = "First"},
        new Entry{Id = "two", Value = "Second"},
        new Entry{Id = "tri", Value = "Third"},
    };
```

I expect to be serialized as follows:

```
{
    one: {Title: "First"},
    two: {Title: "Second"},
    tri: {Title: "Third"}
}
```

Is it possible? Something near ContractResolver?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                       arr.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => new { Title = x.Value }));
```

or
[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
string json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer()
             .Serialize(arr.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => new { Title = x.Value }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
               { "one", "First" },
               { "two", "Second" },
               { "three", "Third" }
           };

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(keyValues);
```